# Access all associations, including nested attributes, before save model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I have an `Order`, an `Item` and a `Product` model.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :order
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end
```

I need to calculate how many boxes every `Item` has (`item.units/item.product.units_per_box`), in a `before_save` callback, but I can't access the nested attributes, just the persisted items.

I've this in the `Order` model:

```
before_save :calculate_boxes, on: [:create, :update]

def calculate_boxes
  self.boxes = 0
  self.items.each do |item|
    self.boxes += item.units / item.product.units_per_box
  end
end
```

But, how I said, it just calculates the persisted items.

Don't know if it matters, but I am using @nathanvda's [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to manage nested attributes on the create/edit form.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like not following convention. You can also use `after_save` if it only gives you the persisted items

Comment: If I user an `after_save` callback to do the calculations and then save the Order, it will fire an infinite loop.
I want to set the total amount of boxes ordered in the order, units are stored in Item model and the unit per box in de product model.

Comment: Try using self.items.collect. That should work. Also i would suggest you to use unless item.marked_for_destruction? inside the loop.

Comment: Also using on: [:create, :update] doesn't make much sense. before_save callback silently ignores "on" arguments. I would suggest you to use before_create and before_update callbacks instead.

Comment: @Akshay `.collect` worked nice. Please, post your comment as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `self.items.collect`. That should work. Also i would suggest you to use `unless item.marked_for_destruction?` inside the loop.